# How to use a Discord emoji in a C# if statement

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm making a shop command for my bot, with the chestnut, ring, tangerine, doughnut and pick emojis in it as a test run. When I try to input the :chestnut: emoji as the item to purchase, it will save it as 'item', but it doesn't seem to be the same as ":chestnut:" in the if statement

```
[Command("buy")]
public async Task Buy(string item)
{
    if (item == ":chestnut:" || item == ":ring:" || item == ":tangerine:" || item == ":doughnut:" || item == ":pick:")
    {
        await ReplyAsync($"{item} purchased!");
    }
    else
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Please enter of of the correct item emojis in order to purchase");
    }
}
```

I've tried with the other emojis as well, and I still get the response from the else area

Comment: The emoji is likely just a Unicode code point, and you should be comparing to that

Comment: @BradleyDotNET where would I find the unicode information for it, and how would I represent it?

Comment: You can get information about emojis from the unicode.org site. For example: here's some info about the [chestnut](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html#1f330) emoji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work. Just copy/paste the emojis into double-quotes. They're characters after all.

```
[Command("buy")]
public async Task Buy(string item)
{
    if (item == "" || item == "" || item == "" || item == "" || item == "⛏")
    {
        await ReplyAsync($"{item} purchased!");
    }
    else
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Please enter of of the correct item emojis in order to 
        purchase");
    }
}
```

This solution assumes that the `item` variable is coming through as an emoji itself

Answer (score 1):

You could add a breakpoint at the if Statement
and see what is passed to your funnction as the item string and then use that in your if Statement instead of ":chestnut:".
Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of this tbh, worked excellently